# Is there a collinearity issue when using: x, dummy indicating extreme negative value of x and their interaction?

Tags: estimation, interaction, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding, endogeneity

I was wondering whether I can build my baseline model using the following variables without incurring in any multicollinearity issue:

1. $X_1$= Net capital flows over GDP (which may be positive and negative)
2. $X_2$= Dummy variable tagging extreme negative values of $X_1$
3. $X_3$= Interaction term $X_1*X_2$
4. $X_4$= Net migration over population (which may be positive and
   negative)
5. $X_5$= Dummy variable tagging extreme positive values of $X_4$
6. $X_6$= Interaction term $X_4*X_5$

I would be very grateful if you may help me understanding this.

Comment: Can you reconstruct any of the variables with a linear combination of the others? I doesn't look like it to me. I'm not sure if that is really a conclusive check though. Are you clipping the extreme values of $X_1$?

Comment: I am taking the lower 20 percent tail as extreme negative values of X1 (that is I am taking those values in order to construct X2). And I do the same for the other variable of interest (but taking the top 20 percentile values).

Comment: I think you'd need $X_3=X_2+X_1$ to get multicolinearity. That said, do you need both $X_2$ and $X_3$ in the model?

Comment: I guess so. Because usually when you have a "crisis" dummy that you want to interact with another phenomenon you always keep: x, crisis dummy, x*crisis. In my case the crisis is referred to the x itself so it's a bit unusual. I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These won't be collinear (assuming you have the data).

A rank deficient data matrix $X$ would a screwy, degenerate case. For example, if $x_i$ is *never* extremely negative or if you have only 1 observation where $x_i$ is extremely negative, your $X$ matrix will be rank deficient.

A more likely problem is that you may have poor estimates of your crisis condition coefficients if the crisis condition (i.e. $x_i < c$) is rare.

#### Further Explanation

Your model is effectively estimating different intercept and slope depending on whether you're in the case $x_{i} < \gamma$ or case $x_{i} \geq \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the cutoff for $x_{i}$ being "extremely negative."

Define dummy variable $d_i$ as:

$$d_{i} = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 1 & \text{ if }x_{i} < \gamma \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$

Consider the model
$$y_i = b_0 + b_1 x_i + b_2 d_i + b_3 d_i x_i + \epsilon_i$$

- Q: What's the intercept if $x_i \geq c$? Answer: $b_0$
- Q: What's the intercept if $x_i < c$? Answer: $b_0 + b_2$
- Q: What's the slope on $x_i$ if $x_i \geq c$? Answer: $b_1$
- Q: What's the slope on $x_i$ if $x_i < c$? Answer: $b_1 + b_3$

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I noticed that the coefficient attached to _X1_ and _X3_ have always opposite sign but more or less the same magnitude. This suggests that in absence of the condition represented by the dummy variable _X2_ (that is very negative values of _X1_ ), the variable _X1_ has a negative effect, but when the condition applies it has a positive effect of the same magnitude, resulting in an overall null effect. I am afraid that my results may be driven by how I created the condition, that is the dummy variable; in a sense it selects only extremely negative values of _X1_